# how to ignore a file using .gitignore

Tags: git

I deleted a file `path/to/the/file.cpp`, which is the relative path from top of the git  repository but I want to that file be ignored by `git status`.

Tried put following patterns in the `.gitignore` files but seems none of them works.

```
**/file.cpp
file.cpp
path/to/the/file.cpp
```

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: What "not works" means exactly? They surely do work.

Comment: Is the file *already tracked* by Git (i.e. did you add and commit it before)? It will keep showing up in `git status` until you commit the removal. `.gitignore` only hides untracked files.

Comment: @MattiVirkkunen The file is already tracked by git. According to your description, seems I can't achieve what I want - I want git to ignore that I deleted a file already committed in the repo.. Sound odd? Maybe. But I that is what I want for some reason..

Comment: Is the reason you don't specify why you want to do this and only say "for some reason" because the reason is a silly workaround for something that should be fixed properly?

Answer (score 2):

this is what you must to

```
git rm path/to/the/file.cpp
```

and now when  your git ignore should work

**.gitignore**

```
path/to/the/file.cpp
```

As Matti Virkkunen pointed out, your file must have been already tracked by git.